# Simplest architecture for service to service data exchange

Tags: c#, web-services, architecture, rabbitmq

I have a public server with web services (.Net) that collect data and uploaded files from different mobile apps and I need to synchronise it with an internal intranet server.

The intranet server is deeply protected by firewall and organisation policies.

I think this is a pretty common scenario where messages and brokers could be used, something like Rabbitmq or Nservicebus, but I'm not an expert on it.

As the data is only to be sent from the external server to the intranet one in unidirectional and asynchronous way I was thinking not to add another layer of indirection to the architecture and just use the web services exposed also for server to server communication.

The approach would be like:

1. An intranet windows serivce  would poll regularly and at different scheduled intervals the external web service to know if there is new data to get (maybe from a certain point in time)
2. The web service would respond with the list of the new data and files
3. The windows service would iterate with calls to get all the data to be inserted in the intranet and download the uploaded files.

What are the risks of this approach? Would be better that the external web service would respond only a link to a huge zipped file response with all the data and files in it?

Should I use a something like RabbitMq also for a so simple scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are literally dealing with files, you might want to think about something even simpler.  FTP (more specifically sftp) might fit your needs better, and be FAR simpler to implement.